# Order of wire statements change behavior

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment, iverilog

I have the following data transition in my state machine:

```
wire VALID_PKT = (FIFO_DATAIN[7] == 1) & (FIFO_DATAIN[6] == 0)& (FIFO_DATAIN[5] == 1) & (FIFO_DATAIN[1] == 1) & (FIFO_DATAIN[0] == 1);
wire SET_RESET = FIFO_DATAIN[3];

reg RESET;
always @(*) begin
    case (CurrentState)
        STATE_DECODE: begin
            if(VALID_PKT) begin
                RESET = SET_RESET;
            end
        end
    endcase
end
```

This is the one place where `RESET` is changed.

My intention is: Only in state DECODE, when the packet is valid, then assign the value to the register. Where it should stay until the next (valid) packet comes and changes it.

When I simulate this with iVerilog I get unexpected results. Specifically, when an invalid packet (`8'b00000000`) comes, `RESET` is set to zero. But this should not happen because `VALID_PKT` is not true.

Now the strange part: If I swap the wire assignments, i.e. I write

```
wire SET_RESET = FIFO_DATAIN[3];
wire VALID_PKT = (FIFO_DATAIN[7] == 1) & (FIFO_DATAIN[6] == 0)& (FIFO_DATAIN[5] == 1) & (FIFO_DATAIN[1] == 1) & (FIFO_DATAIN[0] == 1);
```

then I get the expected result.
This is weird since I think the order of wire assignments should not matter.

Is there any subtlety about wire assignments that I am not aware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition. You have a combinational `always` block and have not assigned `RESET` in all possible branches. Specifically, if `VALID_PKT` goes false, how could `RESET` go back to its previous value? You might want to conver your always block from combinational to synchronous.

Comment: Great that's it. I created a `updateReset` and `nextReset` register which are always set in the combinational block and then transfered to `RESET` in the synchronuous block. Have already read that in a comb block all variables should always be set. But in this case I don't understand because I wrote: "[...] assign to the register. Where it should stay until the next (valid) packet comes and changes it., i.e. I _don't_ _want_ `RESET` at its previous value. Could you elaborate how exactly it comes to that race condition?

Comment: You get a latch when you miss an assignment in a branch. The race is between the latch enable(VALID_PKT) and its data input (SET_RESET).